# Prolog findall function XPCE

Tags: swi-prolog, findall, xpce

```
:-consult('external data base.pl').

listaw:-
    new(SS, dialog('Rekordy w bazie wiedzy')),
    send(SS, display, new(W3,text('some text'))),
    new(M,menu(von,cycle)),
    findall(B,failure(B,_,_),Y),
    send_list(M, append, Y),
    send(SS,open).
```

with external Data base with facts: `failure(aaa,bwww,cdd).`

I have error:

```
26 ?- listaw. ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated ^ Exception: (18) pce_util:send_list(user:@18495295/menu, append, _G534) ?
```

What is the problem? When I have all facts in the same file with code above, everything works... but I want to use external data base...`enter code here`

Comment: Tried your code above, both with the `failure/3` fact in the same file as the `listaw/0` predicate and in an external file. It worked in both cases without throwing any exception.

Comment: @Paulo Moura ... strange. Did you cleaned dynamic memory after compiling code with predicade in the same file and before compiling with predicate in external file?

Comment: I restarted the Prolog interpreter between the two experiments. Are you sure that your database file is being successfully loaded? Best to wrap the call to `consult/1` in an `initialization/1` directive. This way you will get a printed warning if the directive fails. Also, using arbitrary queries as directives instead of the `initialization/1` directive is bad programming style.

Comment: Thanks! I know where is the problem. IF in database is blank record: failure(_,_,_) - then the program isn't working... . I had something like this... .